# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel on apche reverse proxy

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, centos7

I have migrated Apache reverse proxy server from Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4 from Centos 5.7 to Centos 7.3
and configure the new certificate on it
and user complain that The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

If anyone knows solution, please post the solution

Comment: Are there any relevant messages in your logs ?

Comment: client connection has nothing to do with reverse proxy connection. You could clear up where the problem really lies and check error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue caused due to client system can work on lower version of tsl

I have changed 
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2

to 
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3

and my issue resolved